# I am using react mui @mui/x-date-pickers, please tell me how to change color of DatePicker selected area

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

We are using MUI based on React. I am using DatePicker from @mui/x-date-pickers library in MUI. I am using version 6.0.3.
However, as shown in the image below, when the first selected day is selected, the specified color is changed. When the calendar window is opened again, the default color is displayed, but when another area is clicked, the specified color is changed. Is there a way to solve this problem? I did a search and couldn't find it, so I'm asking. Please let me know if the search method is incorrect. Help me

[image]
[image]
[image]

The code used is below please help

```js
import { LGTheme } from '@libs/color';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { koKR } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/locales';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';

const DatePickerTest = () => {
    return (
        <LocalizationProvider
            dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}
            adapterLocale={'ko'}
            localeText={koKR.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText}
            dateFormats={{ monthAndYear: 'YYYY년 MM월' }}
        >
            <DatePicker
                label=""
                format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                slotProps={{
                    textField: {
                        size: 'small',
                    },
                    day: {
                        sx: {
                            ['&[data-mui-date="true"] .Mui-selected']: {
                                // Reset the background color of the selected date
                                backgroundColor: 'blue',
                            },
                            ':not(.Mui-selected)': {
                                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                                borderColor: LGTheme[0],
                            },
                            '&.Mui-selected': {
                                color: '#fff',
                                backgroundColor: LGTheme[0],
                                borderColor: LGTheme[0],
                                ':hover': {
                                    color: '#fff',
                                    backgroundColor: LGTheme[0],
                                    borderColor: LGTheme[0],
                                },
                            },
                            ':hover': {
                                color: '#fff',
                                backgroundColor: LGTheme[0],
                                borderColor: LGTheme[0],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                }}
            />
        </LocalizationProvider>
    );
};

export default DatePickerTest;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `.Mui-selected` class, which only applies to the selected date, not the current date. The current date is the one that is highlighted when you open the calendar, and it may or may not be the same as the selected date. The current date has a different class, `.MuiPickersDay-root`, which you need to target in your `sx` prop.

To fix your issue, you need to pass the `.MuiPickersDay-root` class along with the `.Mui-selected` class in your `sx` prop.

For example:

```
<DatePicker
  slotProps={{
    day: {
      sx: {
        "&.MuiPickersDay-root.Mui-selected": {
          backgroundColor: "red",
        },
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-shape-phhsgd?file=/demo.js).

Comment: you are a genius thank you I couldn't figure out the direction, but thank you for solving it. If you don't mind, can you give me some reference material for that part? I can't find it, but even if I look at the MUI data, I can't find an explanation on how to apply that part, so I'm asking just in case.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help. I wrote it based on my own knowledge and experience with MUI. I don't have a specific reference for it, but you can verify it by inspecting the elements in the browser or reading the source code of MUI. Is there something unclear or incorrect about the sentence? If so, please let me know and I'll try to explain it. - @LeeHoSeop

Comment: No, no problem. I asked if there were any reference materials or how to apply MUI CSS that I could study on my own. Thanks for solving it.